# Android - how to get access to a Service's methods and variables?

Tags: android, android-service

After I launch a service like in the code below, I need to get access to the methods and variables in this service class.

```
ComponentName comp = startService(new Intent(this, ClipboardService.class));
```

I can't access the methods and variables through the comp variable. How do I set up a variable so I can gain access to the contents of the ClipboardService.class in this case? Thanks.

Comment: Use `bindService()` instead of `startService()` for this scenario.

Comment: An example of `bindService()` in action can be seen here: http://blog.blundell-apps.com/notification-for-a-user-chosen-time/

Comment: Thanks, I'll be looking into binding the service! Go ahead and write this as the answer if you like (CommonsWare or Blundell).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bindSerivce() is probably the proper way of doing this, but I found my own cheap way of doing what I needed to do while still using startService(). I moved the methods/variables in question into the activity that launches the service. I access the methods I need in this activity instead where I will first stop the service, create a new intent and relaunch the service and sending the updated variables through intent.putExtra(). onStartCommand() in service then extracts the variables. This seems to work well enough for what I'm doing.